# Finding the words or sentence that is followed by a search word and put them into a dictionary python

Tags: python, nlp

I have to find the words or sentence that follow a search word and put them into a dictionary. My data is in the pdf which I already extract it to a text using PyPDF2 library. I am new to NLP and I don't know how to implement this part of code.
I know how to find 1 word that follows the search word, but sometimes it is a word, sometimes it is sentence which can be identify by **\n**.

> the text example:
>
> ["CODE: ID\nStudy of Men's brain ID\nBased upon 16",  '3 valid cases
> out of 76',  '33 total cases.\n•Mean: 54695.29\n•Minimum:
> 8.00\nVariable Type:  'numeric \nHEALTH: h1 - Health in general\n xxx',  ' ccc']

```
import PyPDF2
search_keywords=['CODE','LVI','HEALTH']


pdfFileObj = open('df.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(5)
text=(pageObj.extractText())
text=text.split(",")
text
```

the out put should be :

```
{"CODE":"ID"
"VIS":none
"HEALTH":"h1 - Health in general"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on Regular Expressions, which are implemented in the `re` module in Python. Regular expressions (AKA regex) let you search for patterns of text in addition to key words. This will be useful for your NLP work. The `re` documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and you can find [a tutorial here](https://regexone.com).

This code accomplishes what you're after:

```
import re
text=["CODE: ID\nStudy of Men's brain ID\nBased upon 16", '3 valid cases out of 76', '33 total cases.\n•Mean: 54695.29\n•Minimum: 8.00\nVariable Type: numeric \nHEALTH: h1 - Health in general\n xxx', ' ccc']

results={}
    
for keyword in ['CODE','LVI','HEALTH']:
    keyword_found=False
    for sentence in text:
        result=re.search(f'({keyword}): (.+)\n',sentence) #this searches for each keyword and captures any text after a colon+space and before \n
        if result:
            keyword_found=True
            results.update({result.group(1):result.group(2)})
            break
    if keyword_found==False:
        results.update({keyword:None})

print(results)

#{'CODE': ' ID', 'LVI': None, 'HEALTH': ' h1 - Health in general'}
```

If you need to change the search pattern, you need to modify the search parameter in `re.search(f'({keyword}): (.+)\n',sentence)`, e.g. if you want two lines after they keyword, the search parameter would be `f'({keyword}): (.+\n.+)\n'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot how this search will look if I want to to add one more sentence after \n, for example the code will be like CODE : ID, Study of Men's brain

Comment: I've added an extra paragraph to the bottom, and added a link to a tutorial on RegEx that should help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `str.splitlines` to split your text on newlines;
- `str.split` with `maxsplit=1` to split your text on `':'`.

Since we never split on spaces, it doesn't matter whether the value after the search word is only one word or a full sentence.

```py
texts = ["CODE: ID\nStudy of Men's brain ID\nBased upon 16",'3 valid cases out of 76','33 total cases.\n * Mean: 54695.29\n* Minimum: 8.00\nVariable Type: numeric\n HEALTH: h1 - Health in general\nxxx', ' ccc']
search_keywords = ['CODE','LVI','HEALTH']

pairs = [tuple(word.strip() for word in sentence.split(':', maxsplit=1)) for text in texts for sentence in text.splitlines()]
pairs_dict = dict(pair for pair in pairs if len(pair) == 2)

result = {k: pairs_dict.get(k) for k in search_keywords}

print(result)
# {'CODE': 'ID', 'LVI': None, 'HEALTH': 'h1 - Health in general'}
```